# Video Not Seeking properly with libmedia Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, mediacontroller, encryption

I am using libmedia to play encrypted video files. The video Plays successfully and there is no video distortion or any type of pause during video playtime and also it pause and play with mediacontroller very well.

The problem is when i try to forward or rewind video it stops and buffering for long time like for 1 minute. I tried to use both Encryption methods BUT NO LUCK with the seek video issue.

```
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding

AES/CFB/NoPadding
```

Please help me out. I am in very tight deadline.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.4 added a special support for the forward/rewind issue, with the restriction to use a **CTR** mode transformation, such as `AES/CTR/NoPadding`.