# Seeking backward the media files being played in Android devices by HTTP streaming fails in Android Video View

Tags: android, streaming, seek, android-videoview

I am trying to play video on an Android device from the memory. In the sense my files are encrypted and stored in SD card so to play these files I cannot decrypt the files and store on SD card  because of security issues as anyone can access the SD card and get the decrypted file. So I have to decrypt the file chunk by chunk and feed the data to the VideoView  in Android. So my task is to play the media files by decrypting it on the fly i.e. in memory decryption and streaming like concept.

So for this I had set up a HTTPServer with the help of NanoHTTPD server and convert the file datapath to url type by using and feeding it to the VideoView. and the server decrypts and does buffering of Video files. Everything work like charm but when I do seeking backward i.e. seeking back to the current position of the video being played I get "Unspecified media file error" and the VideoView hangs. So can any one please help me on how to make a streaming media server that can be seekable backward too.

Any help is appreciated. As from two weeks I am stuck in seeking the file backward while streaming using HTTP server.

Comment: You should add related code

Comment: libmedia does all that work for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409972/video-not-seeking-properly-with-libmedia-android